# Publish incompleto en Azure websites

Tags: css, visual-studio, azure

mi duda es la siguiente.

Cuando voy a publicar mi cambio en los sitios de Azure desde Visual Studio 2013 hago el "rebuild" y el "clean" previo a la publicació del sitio. Una vez terminada la publicación no se ven reflejados los cambios de CSS.

Los cambios realizados son básicos referentes a Css. Probandolo localmente se ve pero al publicarlo no.

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Comment: Has limpiado el cache?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the behavior I am expecting by doing the following. Might not be the best approach, but it is functional and I can't see any major flaws on it.

On Site.Master, replace this line:

```
<webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
```

with these ones:

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" runat="server" />
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" runat="server" />
```

Comment: brother! estás en la version en español, traduce :D Bienvenido a SOes

Comment: Ah verdad xD (https://translate.google.com)